# jQuery: Image in tooptip

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have table with products. What I want to do is display product photo in tooptip, after user hover over table row. Each row is one product. Let suppose that I have photos id in rows coded as row identifier.

```
<table>
  <tr id="prod-37">

  </tr>
  <tr id="prod-38">

  </tr>
</table>
```

I want jQuery function that will be product id aware. Link to photo is : /img/products/${id}.jpg

Comment: Did it not work? From your question it looks like you haven't tried a thing and just want someone to write your solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

There is an example of image and tooltip:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html

Answer (score 1):

I would add a marker css class to each of the table rows. Then you can do $(".myMarkerClass").each to put your hover on the row.

http://api.jquery.com/each/ - you will note that the scope is the item you're iterating over.